# how to disable/restrict wireless network adapter on Windows for security?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-registry

Now we are convenient to use the phone as hot-spot. But how to restrict an USB wireless network adapter by connecting a phone to a company's computer?

We do not want our job to be divulged.

Assume some guys in Microsoft or Google, he connects his phone to computer as a USB wireless network adapter, and then sends the code to web server outside.....

I have try registry and group policy on Windows7/10, but none works.

Seems we need to disable all USB port on BIOS, but in that situation, we cannot use ARM-debugger or camera or USB-to-Serial-Adapter. I just want to disable USB wireless network adapter.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "but how to restrict the hot-spot which connects to company's computer from USB?" and "I just want to disable usb hot-spot/ usb wireless network."? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: sorry，i have improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your question. I think you are getting confused between Wireless Hotspot and USB tethering.

I am assuming that you mean connecting the PC to a phone via USB and using USB tethering.

Unfortunately I think there is no way to do so within Windows because its not required anyway. When you plug-in the USB, you do so voluntarily. You can always turn off the usb tethering option from the mobile device.

Comment: You are right, i have improved. Donot Microsoft worry Windows10 code leaked to internet?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is bad. If someone in Microsoft wanted to leak the Windows' code (or anything anywhere), he/she could do it any way, no matter how many blockades you would use. The USB Tethering isn't the only option of data transfer, the "thief" could use anything: Pendrive, their phone as a USB memory, the Internet itself: cloud-uploading sites, mailbox, any chat or forum supporting file upload. It's possible to plug another device to the computer with an ethernet cable and send files with it too. In the worst case, one can open the PC's casing and remove the hard drive with a software he wants to steal (or plug in his own hard drive and copy a software there).

But assuming that you've cut the Internet connection from your employees' computers, and the PCs' casings are shut closed with rivets, well then, apart from the fact that working with such a machine is almost impossible and very frustrating, all you have to do is to somehow disable using USB devices as external memory and internet-sharing devices AND totally disable Ethernet usage. I guess this is something that requires intervention into the system, but it's manageable.
I'm not an expert so I can't tell you how to do it. You can search google for your answer or wait for someone who knows how to do it and will be kind enough to tell you here. Or you can pay to some IT company to do it for you, which is the best option.
You can always put those PC's in additional, bigger casings, that are designed to prevent plugging in any devices, other than those already plugged in (if something like that exist, but I believe it does)

But what I suggest to you is to just leave everything as it is and trust the people you're working with. People hate limitations and there will always be that one person that will break those limitations, just for the sake of doing it.